# What is the difference between Rotation and getComponentRotation?

Tags: math, unreal-engine4

In the UE4 game engine
What is the difference between Rotation and GetComponentRotation?

Try to understand this by documentation on at

https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/Rotation/index.html

But I could not?

I need some details and explanation about this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two methods are from different objects:

[FVector::Rotation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/Rotation/index.html)
[USceneComponent::GetComponentRotation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/GetComponentRotation/index.html)

Both return a rotation object ([FRotator](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FRotator/index.html)) that encodes the rotation in the Yaw/Pitch/Roll representation.

The difference is that the Rotation returns an FRotator object that, if applied to a component, will make the component "look" in the direction of the vector. For example, if you take the difference between the position of a sphere and the position of a player, use Rotation, and then apply the rotation to the player, the player will face the sphere.

GetComponentRotation returns the current orientation of the component in global space.

Comment: Thanks for your time brother :)
I note c++ code like this: GetForwardVector( ).Rotation( ) !!
What is the above code meaning ? what is the relation between GetForwardVector and Rotation of the object ?

Comment: @MohammedK.Abushawish The "forward vector" is a vector pointing in the same direction as the Actor is looking. You can extract a rotation out of it using the Rotation method, as explained in my answer. However, using this method, there is no way to know if there is a Roll component to the rotation since many different Roll value will make the actor look in the same direction. In an FPS game, this is not a problem since there is usually no roll to the rotation. For a plane simulator game, it may be important. The GetComponentRotation gives the current rotation with the correct roll if the rotat

Comment: Thank you very much my friend for this information, but there is still some ambiguity and lack of understanding on some issues .. Thank you again :)